# How to create dynamic database connection with NodeJS, Express, and Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, sequelize.js

how are you doing? Does anyone know how to create database connection dynamically using NodeJS, Express, and Sequelize?

My development team is developing an API for our mobile application, and on the login page, we'll have 3 fields:

- Enterprise Code
- Username
- Password

When the user inputs the "Enterprise Code", I need to go to my default database, which stores all our customers and search the client data based on what was inputted in the field. Let's suppose that the enterprise code is 147, then the API goes to the customer's table into the default database and search for the data where customer_id = 147. That will return the customer data, which also contains its database name, for example, 147_enterprisename, which is a database named "147_enterprisename" referring to this customer.

What I need is: Create a Sequelize connection based on which "Enterprise Code" was typed, like this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dynamic_database_name, 'root', 'root', {
   host: 'localhost',
   dialect: 'mysql',
   pool: {
      max: 10,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    }
})
```

I also need that the API returns the connection to all routes, where is the functions that fetch data from the database and so on.

Comment: You could write a utility function that returns a Sequelize connection object.  For every user request, you'd need to connect, process the user request and then disconnect.  That adds overhead to your application, which could be problematic.  IMHO it would be better designed to have a single database, with customer_id as part of the primary key for all necessary tables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the database is currently running on an already working software, so we're creating the API for a running system, which means that we cannot have a single database, each customer has its only database. Btw, we'll try your solution, ty again.

Comment: @VictorMathiusso I'm facing the same problem let me know if you found any conquer solutions.